# how to find the user is logged in as root in Linux using bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

Here is a simple function that our script uses to find if user is logged in as root.

```
do_check_user(){
    id | grep root 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if test "$?" != "0"
        then
            echo ""
            echo " Invalid login, Please logon as root and try again!"
            exit 0
    fi
}
```

I do not completely understand how this function works. I tried some searching online to find bits and parts of how it is implemented. but it is still not clear to me.

Especially these lines:

```
id | grep root 1>/dev/null 2>&1
    if test "$?" != "0"
```

I tried doing step by step. But I get error

```
id | grep root 1
grep: 1: No such file or directory
```

if you could explain me this syntax and what it is doing, it will be very helpful

Thanks

Comment: The second argument to grep is supposed to be a file. The file named "1" does not exist in the current directory.

Comment: The line with grep contains output redirection operators (`1>/dev/null` and `2>&1`), and is supposed both stderr (standard error output channel, `2>`) and stdout (standard output channel, `1>`, usually written just `>`) into /dev/null (aka, nowhere).

Comment: That's a terrible way of doing the test, by the way. Suppose you had a user named `grooten` or even a group named `arrowroot_biscuits`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `id` - print real and effective user and group IDs
2. `grep` searches through the output of id for root
3. `1>/dev/null 2>&1` sends `stdout/stderror` to `/dev/null` ; therefore you won't see the output `1>/dev/null` sends only `stdout to /dev/null`
4. `if test "$?" != "0"` checks the status of the last executed command which is `grep`, if it is `0` means sucessful and if it is not `0`, you will get the messages.

Comment: thanks for elaborate answer. In point 3 above,  is stdout or stderr from grep send to `/dev/null`. and what does final `2>&1` mean?

Comment: 1 is stdout. 2 is stderr.
`2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout and by sending `1>\dev\null`, both of them will be send to `\dev\null`; [Cool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21)

Answer (score 2):

In `bash`, you can just test `$UID`:

```
if ((UID==0)); then
   # I'm root
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply can use `whoami` command.

```
#!/bin/bashyou
if [[ $(whoami) == 'root' ]] ; then 
  echo "it's root"
fi
```

**EDIT** Only for bash:
you can also you $EUID variable which refers to user identifier, so in root case it equals `0`

```
(($EUID == 0)) && echo 'root'
```

Comment: shouldn't whomai be in back tics?

Comment: @EJK, This answer, at this time, has not been edited and you're confusing it with a similar answer which is employing the legacy use of backticks over `$(..)`, which some consider the latter to be the current more preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

Try `whoami`:

`do_check_user() { test $(whoami) = root; }`

Comment: what is test in the above?

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of people here are using operands == and != to compare true and false bits, I would suggest using nothing for the == to represent true and just using ! for false.

EG

```
if ((UID)); then echo 'This means the test is Boolean TRUE and the user is not root'
if ((!UID)); then echo 'This means the test is Boolean FALSE and the user is root'
```

Or if comparing a numerical variable to Boolean TRUE or FALSE

```
if [[$a]]; then echo "If the variable 'a' is a 1 then it's Boolean TRUE"
if [[!$a]]; then echo "If the variable 'a' is a 0 (zero) then it's Boolean FALSE"
```

When comparing TRUE or FALSE the operations == and != is not needed, this saves a few key strokes too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `whoami`:

```
if [ `whoami` == "root" ] ; then
    echo "root"
fi
```